# Why I need a Id Interface to implement a repository generic c#?

Tags: c#, entity-framework, generics

I start to implement a Generic Repository, I just have a database with table .. I'm googling and I found some implentation of Repository and Unit of Work, but I don't understand why I need this code

```
**IEntity.cs:**

public interface IEntity<T> 
{
    T Id { get; set; }
}

**Entity.cs:**

public abstract class BaseEntity { 

}

public abstract class Entity<T> : BaseEntity, IEntity<T> 
{
    public virtual T Id { get; set; }
}
```

Why I need an Id in my base entity if I just have a table with a primary key?

[This is the link](http://techbrij.com/generic-repository-unit-of-work-entity-framework-unit-testing-asp-net-mvc)

Thanks

Comment: _"Why I need an Id in my base entity"_ - so you can CRUD through generic code. Why did you pick this tutorial? It has an afwul explanation-to-code ratio. It just says _"copy this code"_ without explaining what it does.

Comment: Can you suggest a better code?

Comment: Just a suggestion. Generalizing stuff isn't the best option everytime. I end up dealing with "let's optimize this query that entity generated when my application scaled" and sometimes that optimization isn't so easy when all your application is based on CRUD generic repos. Idea is to not overuse this generic repo. One good reference, at least for me is the following: http://thedatafarm.com/

Comment: Thanks to all for suggest